# Как в питоне сделать структуру для хранения констант?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

У меня есть данные карточек, которые я хочу хранить. Каждая карточка содержит: `имя карты`, `ссылка на изображение`, `список слов` и `ключевая буква`. 
У меня есть несколько десятков таких карточек. Я ожидаю, что структура карточек в ближайшем времени может начать меняться и будут добавляться\удаляться поля.
Работать это будет как лямбда на сервере амазона, по этому при каждом действии будет новый вызов и новая инициализация всех данных.

**Вот такую структур создал с начала:**

```
class CardData:
    class Card1:
        title = 'Card 1'
        image_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/...'
        words = ['postgame', 'amongst', 'megaton', 'montage', ...]
        key_letter = 't'

    class Card2:
        title = 'Card 2'
        image_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/...'
        words = ['portside', 'riposte', 'deport', 'poser', ...]
        key_letter = 'r'
```

Теперь я могу обращаться к своим данным например так `getattr(CardData, 'Card1').words`

Что меня смутило:
1. Мне не понравилось все время писать `getattr`.
2. Вложенные классы все должны быть одной структуры. И хочется, чтобы IDE подсказывала, если я что-то пропускаю.

Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: А вообще данные обычно хранят в базе данных

Comment: Та же sqlite3 идеально подходит для пары десятков карточек

Comment: Ну тогда попытка 2 наиболее близка к адекватному варианту. А пихать класс внутрь класса и делать каждую карточку отдельным классом это что-то странное

Comment: `dataclasses`, это как раз то адекватное, чего не хватало в python для именно таких задач, и появились они совсем недавно. Я сам хотел предложить этот вариант, пока не дочитал до второго пункта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для версии python 3.7+ стоит использовать `dataclass`:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Card:
    title: str
    image_url: str
    words: list
    key_letter: str


cards = {'card1': Card(title='Card 1', image_url='https: // s3.amazonaws.com /...',
                       words=['postgame', 'amongst', 'megaton', 'montage', ...], 
                       key_letter='t'),
         'card2': Card(title='Card 1', image_url='https://s3.amazonaws.com/...',
                       words=['postgame', 'amongst', 'megaton', 'montage', ...], 
                       key_letter='t')}
```

Получать данные стало проще `cards['card1'].words`.

Для версий младше python 3.7 можно еще попробовать `Enum`

```
from enum import Enum

class ExtEnum(Enum):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        # сделаем Enum из Enum'ов
        if item != '_value_':
            return getattr(self.value, item).value
        raise AttributeError

class CardData(ExtEnum):
    class Card1(Enum):
        title = 'Card 1'
        image_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/...'
        words = ['postgame', 'amongst', 'megaton', 'montage', ...]
        key_letter = 't'

    class Card2(Enum):
        title = 'Card 2'
        image_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/...'
        words = ['portside', 'riposte', 'deport', 'poser', ...]
        key_letter = 'r'
```

Данные получать все так же удобно `CardData['Card2'].words`.